# Replacing word except when it is between letters

Tags: php, regex, replace, preg-replace

For example I would like to change every "hi" to hello
The problem is when I try to do it I get into some kind of problems.
It translates other words badly like:
 from "his dog is nice" to "hellos dog is nice"
How can I fix it
(I am using php)

Comment: use word boundaries.. `\bhi\b`.. Apply this regex on preg_replace,

Comment: Please post your code so I can give better suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `\b` around `hi`:

```
/\bhi\b/
```